# How do I update my website cached version on Google cachedview?

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, responsive, google-chrome-console

I am developing a website and I faced an issue today on my site, I will try to briefly explain the scenario hoping anyone could give a proper explanation for it.

My website is a WordPress website and I have the coming soon page activated so users will be redirected to it.

Two days ago I turned that plugin off by mistake and users were able to see my page. Today I turned it back on, and that's where the issue arises.

In full web (desktop) the coming soon page is visible and working fine, but when I hit the responsive view on my chrome browser the page is still available and the welcome page is not. In the sources tab, I can see the hosted directory being loaded so I went to the hosted directory (public_html) and I hid the folder that contains all the assets (renamed it to .foldername).

I hit refresh still loads the old page when I hit ctrl+shift+r I get the new version. On Firefox the scenario isn't reproducible it just happens on responsive view on Google Chrome browser.

Can anybody explain to me what's happening I assume it has something to do with Google caching my webpage and never updating it. But if like to hear a more professional explanation Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried clearing your Cache in Google Chrome? Also,  Have you enqueued any Scripts or Styles in your `functions.php` file? If so, increase their version number. This will force the browser to download the Scripts and/or Styles again rather than loading any Cached copies.

Hope this helps to resolve your problem(s).